# Performance issues with video on my webpage

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, web-performance

Hello everyone I am currently using Bluehost to host my [website](http://davidnormandesign.com) and the issue is only on desktop because when you view the site on mobile I hide the video and just use an image to help with loading issues and size of the pages. Anyways we currently have the video embedded with YouTube but, the owner does not want to use YouTube which it loads a lot faster etc. When we host the video ourselves with our own shared server with BlueHost the video loads very slow.

I wanted to ask fellow members on SO for some general pointers on what we can do to help with the video. Is there any other third party sites that we can host from that will not show banners or anything else for that matter on the video. We currently have pro service with BlueHost if anyone wanted to check that out and see what specs are you can visit that [here](https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/shared-hosting-prices#shared). The video is about 3 or 4-Mb in size and i'm pretty sure it is the size of the video and also the shared hosting server from BlueHost that is slowing it down.

Any additional idea's will be greatly appreciated whether they are third party advice or advice on BlueHost server or even any other way within the code etc. to help with performance issue with video on desktop view cause again we hide the video and use an image for the mobile versions. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Video hosting and streaming services typically use specialist streaming servers to achieve high quality and speed, along with CDN systems.

The streaming server will ensure the video file is properly prepared, is available in the right formats and usually will also have multiple  versions of the video in different bit rates to provide Adaptive Bit Rate Streaming (ABR).

ABR allows the client to choose the best bit rate at and moment depending on its screen size and the current network conditions. See here for a little more explanation and an example of the bit rate changes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402

There are commercial hosted video steaming services available such as:

- https://www.brightcove.com/en/
- https://vimeo.com (plus or pro account, AFAIK, to remove ads and banners)

Or you can create your own streaming server using a commercial offering such as:

- https://www.wowza.com

or opensource ones such as:

- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org

Comment: Ok that was the help I needed. I will check everything out you provided me and when I figure out my best results I will add it here for future help.  Thanks again @Mick