# Video Quality Assessment (No-reference)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, videoquality

I am looking to analyze the quality of videos using some no-reference methods. ie. I don't have a reference video to compare my videos with.

I want to identify frame-freezes, jitter, jerkiness etc. Basically, temporal artifacts.

There's a lot of academic literature available for this (eg. [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1687-5281-2014-40)), but I'm trying to figure out if there is an open source library / tool that I could use. Would this be possible using tools like FFMPEG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are free versions of tools which will allow you do this - e.g.:

- http://www.compression.ru/video/quality_measure/video_measurement_tool.html
- https://github.com/Rolinh/VQMT

One thing that you want to be clear on when selecting a tool is whether you are measuring just the video, or the video and its delivery.

In other words the same video file, could produce very different results when streamed over different networks conditions.

For some use cases, it is actually the video streaming performance which is the critical thing and if this is the case you may want to focus on the network aspects in particular - packet loss, throughput, delay and jitter in particular.

For streaming videos you also need to be aware of the effect adaptive bit rate streaming (ABR) has - it makes measuring hard as the video stream adapts to the network conditions. See here for an example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402