# Generate a video stream from Basler camera grabbing loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, camera, live-streaming

I am a beginner in video streaming and handling.

I need to take the stream from a Basler GiGE camera and display it in a web container.

I am using the `Basler.Pylon` C# API to access the camera and grab images one by one. from the `IGrabResult` object returned, I can access various parameters such as width, height, stride, and of course the byte buffer.

On my PC, I can easily display that in an image window, but what do i need to do to display that in an ASP.NET web application?

**EDIT**

I am not looking for code but more for guidelines, if someone could explain how video streaming works in general, that would work too

Comment: There is a quite good overview of the "whole video streaming works" here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Live_streaming_web_audio_and_video - you can then google on RTSP or HLS C# for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video streaming is quite specialised and in general I would say if you want to stream high quality video over the internet to multiple end suers, its easiest to use a dedicated video streaming server rather than try to build one yourself.

Dedicated video streaming servers can be provided via a hosted service (e.g Vimeo), be a commercial server you install and run (e.g. Wowza) or a freeware streaming server you install and rune (e.g. GStreamer), so you have options there.

A a general rule, the streaming server will break your video into chunks and create multiple bit rate copies of your video. This allows a client to use Adaptive Bit Rate streaming (ABR) and download your video chunk by chunk, selecting the bit rate version for the next chunk depending on the current device and network conditions. HLS and MPEG-DASH are exmaples of ABR streaming protocols.

On a web page you then need a HTNML5 player which can understand this streaming protocol - again there are many examples such as the freeware Shaka and Dash.js players. Integrating these into a web page is very straightforward.

You can observe these in use on services like Netflix and YouTube which will often start at a lower bit rate to ensure a fast start and then 'step up' to higher bit rates until the optimal one for the current network conditions and device is reached. See here for some info on how you can see a graph of this when watching YouTube, for example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402

Having said all the above, it is worth nothing that your case seems to be dealing with a stream of still images. Although all video is really a stream of still images under the covers, it may be that your image is changing infrequently, and hence you may not need some of the techniques above - a lot of the technology of video streaming is to deal with the very large amount of data streaming 30 or 60 high quality frames per second from a server to a client.

If your stream of images, for example, was one every 30 seconds then it may, as Nisus says, be just as easy to simply display the images in your web page and have the web page or app poll the server every 30 seconds (using ASP.NET AJAX in your case) to download the new image.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options - first one is producing series of jpeg-images every few seconds and show them one by one on client using  tag and simple javascript code. Second option is to generate and stream mp4-video and show it on client with some COM-windows media player or html5 control.