# How to build a simple video streaming server?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, streaming, html5-video, blob

I am a newbie in video streaming and I just build a sample website which plays videos. Here i just give the video file location to the video tag in html5. I just noticed that in youtube the video tag contains the blob url and had a look into this. I found that the video data comes in segments and came across a term called pseudo streaming. Whereas it seems likes the website that i build downloads the whole file and plays the video. I am not trying to do any live streaming, just trying to stream local videos. I thought maybe the way video data is received in segments is done by a video streaming server. I came across RED5 open source streaming server, but most of the examples that is given is for live streaming which I am not experimenting on. Its been few days and I am not sure whether i am on the right track

Answer (score 1):

The segmented approach you refer to is to support Adaptive Bit Rate streaming - ABR.

ABR allows the client device or player download the video in chunks, e.g 10 second chunks, and select the next chunk from the bit rate most appropriate to the current network conditions. See here for an example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402

For your existing site, so long as your server supports range requests then you probably are not actually downloading the whole video. With Range Requests, the browser or player will request just part of the file at a time so it can start playback before the whole file is downloaded.

For MP4 files, it is worth noting that you need to have the header information, which is contained in a 'block' or 'atom' called MOOV atom, at the start of the file rather than the end - it is at the end for regular MP4 files. There are a number of tools which will allow you move it to the start - e.g.:

- http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/

You are definitely on the right track with your investigations - video hosting and streaming is a specialist area so it is generally easier to leverage existing streaming technologies and services rather than to build them your self. Some good places to look to get a feel for open source solutions:

- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org
- http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html