# Is it possible to stream large video files on any internet speed while using the media library of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, video, large-files, media-library

I'm currently building my portfolio with wordpress, and I have large video files (each between 2.5gb and 5gb) to display. Youtube and vimeo compress quite a lot the videos, and I'm trying to find an alternative to these website.

I want to use the media library to display the projects, but I wonder if the files will be watchable. Because of their size, I have the fear that the videos will load every 10sec. Am I right, or videos that weight 5gb will run without issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most good quality internet video delivery services, including YouTube and Vimeo will actually create multiple different bit rate versions of your video and then server the highest quality they can depending on the device watching the video and the current network conditions - you can see more info and how to see it in action here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402

At the moment this is the 'state of the art' in the industry for delivery best quality video reliably - you don't have to use YouTube or Vimeo as other hosting services exist or you can even run your own streaming server using something like Wowza or GStreamer. It is worth being aware that this domain is complex and ever changing so you may find it easier to use some hosting service.