# PlayReady DRM request sspk or mss hash key

Tags: drm, playready

My device (HbbTV Set of box) should support PlayReady DRM, but i found that it can't work on [Microsoft test content](https://test.playready.microsoft.com/Content/Content2X). the technical support engineer explain that the test content request `sspk` or `MSS`. But my hardware doesn't support `sspk` or `MSS`. 
What's `sspk` or `MSS`? who can give more detail about them.

Answer (score 1):

MSS is Microsoft Smooth Streaming - a streaming protocol typically used to stream adaptive bit rate media (ABR) streams in the OTT world.

ABR breaks allows the client request different bit rate versions of a each chunk of a video depending on the current network connection and the device type. See more info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402

SSPK is the client porting kit for MSS.

Answer (score -1):

Now, I know that MSS means "Microsoft Smooth Streaming". the protocol for media delivery online. MPEG-DASH and Apple HLS also are used for this.