# video.js: good for buffer preloading and responsive fullscreen renderings?

Tags: javascript, css, video, video.js

I now this question is subjective. Hope it won't get closed because frankly, I cannot find any other source for this informations (including video.js docs). So I try...

I want to use [video.js](https://videojs.com/), I need a simple background video. I know there are simple css ways for this, but I also need to ensure the better playback possible, and I was wondering: does video.js help on this? Does it ensures some kind of optimised playback, don't know, by checking initial buffering or the like?

And if yes, does it have any problem with css ways of getting it fullscreen?

Comment: A lot of the video delivery speed and quality will be dependent on how the video is served on the back end - i.e. whether you use a CDN and an Adaptive Bit Rate streaming protocol (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402 ).

Comment: As far as I can say, starting from v7.0.0, videojs does use adaptive bit rate streaming through HLS (https://blog.videojs.com/introducing-video-js-http-streaming-vhs/)

Comment: Video.js is on the client side and yes video.js does support ABR. But the server side needs to provide it also or else video.js cannot use this feature. Basically the server side needs to make multiple different bit rate versions of the video available, each segmented and transported via HLS or MPEG-DASH (or sometimes Smoothstreaming).

Answer (score 1):

VideoJs is widely using and most popular open source platform for videos. It is very difficult so summarize its advantages and pro's over other video libraries here. But to address your specific questions

> It has a option to preload which you can specify and load frames, media or any metadata

```
videojs('my-player', {
  controls: true,
  autoplay: false,
  preload: 'auto'
});
```

> CSS is highly customizable with very less efforts. See following example.

https://codepen.io/heff/pen/wtrHL

Hope this will help.