# On play preloading video

Tags: html, video

How to do:

- Pre loading video on play
- Change resolution
- Change language

In multiple platforms I see these techniques used but I can't understand which api they use to do these things does anyone have an idea?
(Sorry for the ignorance I'm Junior developer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HTML5 on a browser then there are a set of events which the HTML5 video playback generates at different stages and which you can register to monitor and then take whatever action you want - for example change language etc.

There is a really nice illustration of the various events and their values when a vide plays (at the time of writing) here:

- https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

It's worth noting that the type of features you are describing are usually built into a HTMl5 video player if it is on a website or a native player if it is on Mobile.

For example on a browser the open source DASH if player, https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/latest/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html, will change resolutions for ABR streams  and provide the user controls to change it manually and to set the langage.

On Android the open source ExoPlayer, https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer,  provides similar functionality, and on iOS the built in media library https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation?language=objc, provides similar functionality.

To understand ABR streams and how and why they change resolutions this answer may help: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402)

Comment: For Browser, Fantastic example w3, some good practice for the player management of the pre loaded frame