# How to create a direct public link to my videos

Tags: html, apache, url, video, webserver

I have over 100+ short videos for my project and I need to make direct public links to each of them. I’m not looking to embed videos. I’m looking for links I can make like on the Apache server but a faster process. Similar to this: http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4

Comment: Apache HTTPD is not slow.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think you're getting downvotes because of too much missing info. _"I’m looking for links I can make like on the Apache server but faster"_ doesn't make any sense. What makes that shown MP4 link "faster"? (1) Do you have an online server? (2) Did you use your site's admin panel to upload files to a folder? (3) Why is the link to such uploaded file not what you want? It will be public after-all...

Comment: I was talking about creating links faster and easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different server technologies which will allow you serve static content like mp4 files.

For example node.js supports simple static servers - https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html

A very simple example form the above link can be as basic as:

```js
var express = require('express')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

var app = express()

app.use(serveStatic('public/ftp', { 'index': ['default.html', 'default.htm'] }))
app.listen(3000)
```

You just need to set the correct directory on your server in the app.use.. line.

Note this will not support HLS or DASH, which are adaptive bit rate streaming technologies (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402). For that you will need a specialised streaming server, but it sounds like your use case is simpler than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Amazon S3 Bucket.
You just need to upload your video files over there,make some configurations and you are good to go.

Speed will be pretty fast as it is hosted on S3.
You can upload files through this tutorial.
https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/tutorials/create/beginner/s3-video/