# How YouTube deliver videos to client computer?

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing

I am trying to understand the video broadcasting system.
In most of the cases. I saw that. when we want to play a video on client computer. We just asl our client to upload a video and then we save that video in our system and then by using the URL of the video. We play that video in the client browser.

URL Something like that : https://*****.com/888.mp4 (Or any supported format)

But when I try to check the system of youtube. it was a totally different system.
Because instead of delivering the video URL. Youtube is delivering video in the chunk of files
Like this [image]

So I wan to know that. what kind of system is this?
What video format is youtube using to save the videos at his server?
and why youtube using this system?

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Check into MediaSource Extensions.  HLS and/or DASH is commonly loaded this way.

Comment: To add to Brad;s comment, you can actually see more detail on how YouTube uses HLS and DASH as it streams by looking at the 'stats for nerds' option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402