# How to play digital Ocean hosted video on Android?

Tags: android, digital-ocean, android-videoview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

How to play video hosted on DigitalOcean Space on Android app?
What is the type of video that Digital Ocean offers like MPEG-DASH, HSL or RTMP, etc?
Can I use Exoplayer to play Digital Ocean videos?

Answer (score 0):

DigitalOcean is a general purpose cloud computing provider and Spaces is its's AWS S3-API compatible object storage solution - i.e. it's not a dedicated video host solution.

You can store and access your video there, but the format, codecs containers etc, are up to you.

It does have a built in CDN which you may find helps video response times, but as with all CDN's you probably want to test and compare to decide which is best for you.

For streaming video you can:

- use simply HTTPS streaming, essentially just downloading the video in chunks and playing it as you download it.
- use a dedicated streaming protocol like HLS or HASH which will allow you offer multiple bit rates to improve the user experience. More on ABR streaming here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402

This usual way to support HLS and/or DASH is by using a streaming server - there are open source ones available, e.g. http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html

In either case, if you video is mp4 you also need to make sure the header information, the 'moov atom' is at the start as the player needs this to allow it start playback. There are tools to allow you do this and more info here: https://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/