# How to convert normal URI to dash URI?

Tags: android, firebase-storage, uri, exoplayer, exoplayer-media-item

Currently, I have been making streaming video player app. so for that reason I want to use dash streaming. I have a normal URI of video from my firebase storage. but for dash streaming, I think I need a file that ends with .mpd.

```
ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
player.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(**dashUri**));
player.prepare();
```

**what I have to do to convert normal to URI which ends with .mpd.**

So, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you share example of url you want to convert

Comment: video url which generates from firebase storage.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have to covert the video file to a fragmented format and typically will want to make it available in multiple bit rates, which means transcoding it also.

The reason for this is that DASH is an ABR protocol - it breaks multiple renditions of a video into equal size, time wise, chunks and the player can then request chunk by chunk, choosing the best bit rate version of each chunk depending on the current network conditions and the device type.

See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402

Open source tools exist to create DASH files from mp4 - see some examples here (links correct at time of writing):

- https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/DASH-Support-in-MP4Box
- https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#dash-2