# How to know the size of a file from url befor downloading it?

Tags: android

Hi I am new for android and in my app I have to find the file size before downloading it.

For this I wrote the code below, but it's giving me content length 2588 but the actual size of my file is 745 MB.

Please help me. How can I find the exact file size in MB's?

### code:-

```
URL url = new URL("mu url");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
int file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```

Comment: You will only be able to see value which has been set in content length header field. That value you would be able to access.

Comment: using above url i have to find file size in MB's if you know please help

Comment: please look this .it will help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983073/how-to-know-the-size-of-a-file-before-downloading-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983073/how-to-know-the-size-of-a-file-before-downloading-it)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using the wrong URL/file to get the size of the file you're expecting:

`URL url = new URL("http://adultswim-vodlive.cdn.turner.com/ce8bfc5c729b0587eed7cf08b952c8c4/master.m3u8");`

[M3U8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) files are plain-text playlist files - in your case the file that [your URL is pointing to](http://adultswim-vodlive.cdn.turner.com/ce8bfc5c729b0587eed7cf08b952c8c4/master.m3u8) is actually only `2588` bytes.

Comment: so how can i find size in MB's

Comment: can you please give full code because i am new for android

Comment: The 745 MB file size you're expecting - how do you know the file is 745 MB? What is the file type of that 745 MB file and what URL you're using to access the 745 MB file?

Comment: Actually we are using One Download Manager SDk using abover M3U8 file when i download it's showing 745MB ,But before downloading i want to find that M3U8 file size exactly

Comment: i hope you can help me and you can give solution to my problem

Comment: Your download manager SDK is probably referencing the individual multimedia content present in the playlist and combining them into a single multimedia file and giving it. If your download manager SDK doesn't currently support a size() API, it's not easy to find out the size of the complete multimedia content pointed to by a playlist file like M3U8.

Comment: Please check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799396/figure-out-the-file-size-of-a-m3u8-url-referenced-video - you could probably try something similar, but I don't know anything about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139583/discussion-between-krish-and-ivoid).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this to find file size:

```
String value = null;     
long fileSize = getFileSize(file)/1024;  
if(fileSize >= 1024)
   value = fileSize/1024+" Mb";
else
   value = fileSize+" Kb";


// this method returns file size
public long getFileSize(File f) {
    long size = 0;
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {    
            size += getFolderSize(file);
        }
    } else {
        size=f.length();
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: what is here file? how can i pass url in your code?

Comment: using url i have to find file size did your see my code?